# Initialize boost::optional with ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, option-type

Is the a way to initialize optional like:

```
bool conditional = true;
boost::optional<int> opt = conditional ? 5 : boost::none;
```

Why does the error occur?:

```
main.cpp:31:31: error: operands to ?: have different types ‘int’ and ‘const boost::none_t’
boost::make_optional(cond ? 5 : boost::none);
      |                          ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With simple `if else` I can do this:

```
boost::optional<int> opt;
if (cond)
    opt = 5;
else
    opt = boost::none;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ternary operator requires the left & right to be the same (or convertible) types. `none_t` and `int` aren't the same type. You can probably do `cond ? boost::optional<int>(5) : boost:none`

I don't use boost, so just guessing on syntax based on `std::optional`, but the following does work:

```
std::optional<int> opt = cond ? std::optional<int>(5) : std::nullopt;
```

Answer (score 2):

`?a:b` requires that `a` and `b` have a common type to convert to that C++ can deduce.

`boost::none` and `5` don't have this.

```
auto opt = conditional ? boost::optional<int>(5) : boost::none;
```

that works

```
auto opt = conditional ? 5 : boost::optional<int>();
```

also works.

You can also write a helper

```
auto opt = maybe_optional( conditional, 5 );
```

where

```
template<class T>
boost::optional<T> maybe_optional( bool b, T t ) {
  if (b) return std::forward<T>(t);
  return boost::none;
}
```

Comment: Beware that `maybe_optional` always constructs the `T` argument, which is different from how the ternary operator behaves (this is usually significant, although not in this particular case).  Also, it's incorrect to use `std::forward` on a plain `T` -- either use `std::move` or change the parameter to `T&&` (or actually do neither, since it's a return value).

Comment: @Miral `boost::optional` supports reference types.  `boost::optional<T&>`, `boost::optional<T&&>` and `boost::optional<T>` are all distinct types; `maybe_optional<T>`, `maybe_optional<T&&>` and `maybe_optional<T&>` create different types.  As far as I can tell, all produce correct code in the body with `std::forward` there; `std::forward` is a conditional move, and does the right thing when passed `T&&` and `T&` and `T` with a `T` lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the of the ternary operator needs to be of a single type. The arguments, the left and right of the `:`, thus need to be of the same type, or convertible to the same type.